# future and for yield syntax async or sync?

Tags: scala

I've been using Scala for quite some time now and I am stumbling upon
a very essential question regarding the usage of future with for-yield comprehension.

The for-yield syntax is just a syntactic sugar that simplifies a chain of flatMap/map. Futures are supposed to be a wrapper for async, but it seems like the usage of flatMap/map plays a more synchronous role as it seemingly 'waits' on the result of the previous future call to be computed so it can be manipulated. So this becomes more confusing all of a sudden and makes me return to this fundamental question. Futures are async, but are the usage of map/flatmap (for-yield) also async even though it allows sequential operation inside for-yield?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `map` on a `Future` does not wait, it simply creates a new `Future` which takes the result of the original `Future` when it becomes available and processes it a bit more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `map/flatMap` and `for` expression is used to transform a future to another future and are **asynchronous**.

In case of `map/flatMap`:

```
val future1 = Future {Thread.sleep(10000); 12}
val newFuture = future.map(res => res + 10)
```

In above code block, `future1` is transformed to `newFuture` and it seems synchronous because `res + 10` will be only computed after `future1` is completed and it has to wait for 10 seconds for `future1` to complete and then compute the sum and return this computation as new future. However, the action is completely asynchronous, because they will be executed in different context and i.e. `future1` and `newFuture` will be executed on different context and will not block each other, but however `newFuture` expects `future1` to successfully complete and return value `12` in order to perform `res + sum`, and this makes it looks like synchronous process but technically it is not.

Similarly, in case of `for expression`:

```
val future1 = Future {Thread.sleep(10000); 10}
val future2 = Future {Thread.sleep(15000); 20}
val newFuture = for {
    res1 <- future1
    res2 <- future2
} yield res1+res2
```

In above case, `future1` and `future2` is executed in parallel in different context and when all future completed it will finally yield sum - `res1 + res2`. `future1` takes 10 seconds to complete and `future2` takes 15 seconds, therefore, value is yielded after 15 seconds.

> Note: Because for expressions serialize their transformations, if you
>   don't create the futures before the for expression, they won't run in
>   parallel.

```
val newFuture = for {
    res1 <- Future {Thread.sleep(10000); 10}
    res2 <- Future {Thread.sleep(15000); 20}
} yield res1+res2
```

Above future will take atleast 25 seconds to complete.

On the other hand, if you are using result of one future to another, then it won't run in parallel. Following code is equal to `future1.map(value => {Thread.sleep(15000); 20 + value})`

```
val future1 = Future {Thread.sleep(10000); 10}
def future2(value: Int) = Future {Thread.sleep(15000); 20 + value}
val newFuture = for {
    res1 <- future1
    res2 <- future2(res1)
} yield res2
```

To sum up, if you need to use result of one future's value and then perform certain computation with that value, then use `map/flatMap`. But if you need to execute multiple future concurrently and perform computation of values of these futures, then use `for` expression and know that both are completely asynchronous.

Answer (score 0):

The use case of using a for comprehension is when you have depends on kind of a future.

## Let's explain it with a example:

**FutureB** if it's dependent on **FutureA** value, then you need to wait for **FutureA** value to be computed and then only you can pass it on to **FutureB**.

There's two way to solve it:

### 1. Using A Map:

One of the basic combinators is map, which, given a future and a mapping function for the value of the future, produces a new future that is completed with the mapped value once the original future is successfully completed. You can reason about mapping futures in the same way you reason about mapping collections.
(Taken From https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html#functional-composition-and-for-comprehensions)

Example:

`FutureA.map(FutureB(_))`

### 2. Using A For Comprehension

```
val result = for {
  A <- FutureA
  B <- FutureB(A)
} yield B
```

In the above example, we can see that we chain the dependent futures in respective order, using map and flatmap we get back the result. And we are no way blocking the futures, as for comprehension also returns a Future.

In both the above cases we never block the futures, just that they are sequenced.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of it this way: all useful methods on Future create new callback which is scheduled to run on provided execution context and return a new Future object which is considered `done` when the callback finishes execution.
And if one callback depends on another callback, then it will be executed no earlier than the first finishes. So no threads are blocked.

You can try to visualize it on a piece of paper, that usually helps to see it.